# Jolttransformjson not working from multirecord json file

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a json record as below

```
[{ 
   "1":"valur",
   "2":"bare"
},
{ 
   "1":"valur",
   "2":"bare"
}]
```

need to change colunm names expected output

```
[{ 
   "name":"valur",
   "id":"bare"
},
{ 
   "name":"valur",
   "id":"bare"
}]
```

I am change this value using nifi jolttransfromjson as below screen shot
[image]

this is working fine if we send single record json as below

```
[{ 
   "1":"valur",
   "2":"bare"
}]
```

out put:-

```
[{ 
   "name":"valur",
   "id":"bare"
}]
```

but when I am sending multiple record json it is not working

```
[{ 
       "1":"valur",
       "2":"bare"
    },
    { 
       "1":"valur",
       "2":"bare"
    }]
```

if we send above input i am unable to get my output can anyone help me with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "1": "[&1].name",
        "2": "[&1].id"
      }
    }
  }
]
```